# Not able to read all nested values from RSS feed

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, webforms, rss

I am trying to read from the RSS feed using the ASP.NET Webform. I want to target nested element in the RSS feed.

I used the following code to read values into the grid but it targets all Title tags and fails to read link value.

```
private void PopulateRssFeed()
{
    string RssFeedUrl = "https://feeds.buzzsprout.com/2162688.rss";
    List<Feeds> feeds = new List<Feeds>();
    try
    {
        XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
        //XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc = XDocument.Load(RssFeedUrl);
        var items = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("item")
                     select new
                     {
                         title = x.Element("title").Value,
                         link = x.Element("enclosure").Value,
                         pubDate = x.Element("pubDate").Value,
                         //description = x.Element("description").Value
                     });
        if (items != null)
        {
            foreach (var i in items)
            {
                Feeds f = new Feeds
                {
                    Title = i.title,
                    Link = i.link,
                    //PublishDate = i.pubDate,
                    //Description = i.description
                };
                feeds.Add(f);
            }
        }
        gvRss.DataSource = feeds;
        gvRss.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Below is the complete structure of the RSS file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="https://feeds.buzzsprout.com/styles.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:podcast="https://podcastindex.org/namespace/1.0" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
  <atom:link href="https://feeds.buzzsprout.com/xxxx.rss" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
  <atom:link href="https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/" rel="hub" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" />
  <title>خلف</title>
  <lastBuildDate>Tue, 21 Nov 2023 10:27:48 -0500</lastBuildDate>
  <link>https://khalaf.buzzsprout.com</link>
  <language>ar</language>
  <copyright>@ Copyright</copyright>
  <podcast:locked>yes</podcast:locked>
    <podcast:guid>f33b9b75-9b19-58db-a432</podcast:guid>
    <itunes:author>Author XYZ</itunes:author>
  <itunes:type>episodic</itunes:type>
  <itunes:explicit>false</itunes:explicit>
  <description><![CDATA[<p> This is the description of podcast channel</p>]]></description>
  <itunes:keywords>keyword 1,keyword 2, keyword 3, keyword 4 </itunes:keywords>
  <itunes:owner>
    <itunes:name>Author Name XYZ</itunes:name>
  </itunes:owner>
  <image>
     <url>https://storage.buzzsprout.com/variants/2f1daa412b7c1921.jpg</url>
     <title>Author Logo</title>
     <link></link>
  </image>
  <itunes:image href="https://storage.buzzsprout.com/variants/1daa412b7c1921.jpg" />
  <itunes:category text="Business">
    <itunes:category text="Entrepreneurship" />
  </itunes:category>
  <itunes:category text="Business">
    <itunes:category text="Investing" />
  </itunes:category>
  <itunes:category text="Business">
    <itunes:category text="Management" />
  </itunes:category>
  <item>
    <itunes:title>Episode 1</itunes:title>
    <title>Episode 1 TITLE</title>
    <description><![CDATA[<p> Descrption of first episode </p>]]></description>
    <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p dir='rtl'> Something of first episode </p>]]></content:encoded>
    <itunes:author>AUthor Name</itunes:author>
    <enclosure url="https://www.buzzsprout.com/2162687/827-.mp3" length="7159177" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <guid isPermaLink="false">Buzzsprout-13106827</guid>
    <pubDate>Fri, 30 Jun 2023 10:00:00 +0400</pubDate>
    <itunes:duration>593</itunes:duration>
    <itunes:keywords></itunes:keywords>
    <itunes:season>1</itunes:season>
    <itunes:episode>8</itunes:episode>
    <itunes:episodeType>full</itunes:episodeType>
    <itunes:explicit>false</itunes:explicit>
  </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I only want to read values under `items` such as

```
<title>Episode 1 TITLE</title>
```

```
<description></description>
```

```
<enclosure url="https://www.buzzsprout.com/2162687/827-.mp3" length="7159177" type="audio/mpeg" />
```

and

```
<pubDate>Fri, 30 Jun 2023 10:00:00 +0400</pubDate>
```

```
<item>
    <itunes:title>Episode 1</itunes:title>
    <title>Episode 1 TITLE</title>
    <description><![CDATA[<p> Descrption of first episode </p>]]></description>
    <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p dir='rtl'> Something of first episode </p>]]></content:encoded>
    <itunes:author>AUthor Name</itunes:author>
    <enclosure url="https://www.buzzsprout.com/2162687/827-.mp3" length="7159177" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <guid isPermaLink="false">Buzzsprout-13106827</guid>
    <pubDate>Fri, 30 Jun 2023 10:00:00 +0400</pubDate>
    <itunes:duration>593</itunes:duration>
    <itunes:keywords></itunes:keywords>
    <itunes:season>1</itunes:season>
    <itunes:episode>8</itunes:episode>
    <itunes:episodeType>full</itunes:episodeType>
    <itunes:explicit>false</itunes:explicit>
  </item>
```

The Code that I wrote reads all the title tags outside of the main `<item>`. How can I target items inside `<item>` only and how can I read the URL for the file?

Live RSS feed link: https://feeds.buzzsprout.com/2162688.rss

Comment: From what I understand your question, you are unable to get the attribute value for example `url` in `<enclosure>` tag. Am I correct?

Comment: I solved it using link =  x.Element("enclosure").Attribute("url").Value,``

Comment: @YongShun, yes you are correct. If there is a more optimized way to do all then please do mentioned it.

Comment: Yes, that is the right one (Man I was so closed to post the answer as found out you just post it). I have another suggestion is that you don't need to loop the `items` to add each item into `feeds` array. You can straight way make use of that LINQ query to return `List<Feeds>` and assign to `feeds`.

Comment: Can you post code so that i can mark it as solution as i have not marked by answer as solution as i want to keep it open to see if someone suggest more optimised code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x.Element("<tag name>").Attribute("<attribute name>").Value` is the way to extract the value from the attribute in the tag.

Besides, as mentioned in the comment, you don't need to loop each item from the `items` to add each into the `feeds`.

You can make use of that LINQ query to return the data as `List<Feeds>` and assign to `feeds`.

```cs
feeds = (
            from x in xDoc.Descendants("item")
            select new Feeds
            {
                Title = x.Element("title").Value,
                Link = x.Element("enclosure").Attribute("url").Value,
                PublishDate = x.Element("pubDate").Value,
                //Description = x.Element("description").Value
            }
        ).ToList();
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/azhYsx)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem as i was finding it hard to read the attribute value for enclose

```
title = x.Element("title").Value,
//link = x.Element("enclosure").Value,
link =  x.Element("enclosure").Attribute("url").Value,
pubDate = x.Element("pubDate").Value,
description = x.Element("description").Value
```

I changed following code after looking for any reference.
`link = x.Element("enclosure").Value,` to
`link =  x.Element("enclosure").Attribute("url").Value,`